# AWS EC2 instance type attributes via API

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there some way to get the EC2 instance type details via an API? That is, I'd like to list the various types like 't1.micro', 'c3.xlarge', 'm3.xlarge', and see how much memory they have, local disk space, vCPU, ECU, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now possible via `aws ec2 describe-instance-types` (AWS CLI v2.1.16), or the [DescribeInstanceTypes EC2 API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstanceTypes.html).